# suddenly got error in gradle sync - build tool version 27.0.1 and support version 27.0.1 etc. not found in android studio project

Tags: android, gradle, version-control

Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.1

in my project I am using 25 , but it is showing error for 27.

I opened Android studio project, which was already developed. 
Project was built successfully, but after few days suddenly this error came up in gradle sync. 
I have installed build tools for 27 and sync with that, but it is still giving same error. 
I think it is because of vcs or git used in project, is it possible? 
or any other reason ? how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in your gradle

```
 allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
        }
    }
```